# Windows Phone 8.1 Combobox: Different SelectedItem Template

Tags: combobox, windows-phone-8.1, datatemplate, selecteditem

I want to separate the combobox item templates and the selected item. There are many reference availale but none of them works in **Windows Phone 8.1**.

The concept image:

[image]

Is there any example available?

Comment: What do you want to do with selected item template, do you want to change it color, scale it, change the background ?

Comment: @AbdallahShakhatrƎh Thanks for the reply. I want to have different Items. For example the selected Item has 1 Item and the others have 3 Items with different template of course.

Comment: Can you draw and provide a picture about what exactly do you want to do, this will help me to understand the problem .

Comment: @AbdallahShakhatrƎh, I've added a concept image to my post.